# Number of Contiguous Arrangements of Four Books out of Twelve

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Twelve distinct books are lined up on a shelf. If four of the books are blue, how many arrangements of the books, have all four blue books together?

I don't know if my answer is right but is it 8 arrangements? I believe its 8 arrangements because since 4 blue books must be together, if you keep shifting those books to the right, there are 8 different possibilities. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is almost correct. First, there are nine possible positions for the four books. Take the other eight books. There are seven slots between all of them, and one before all the eight, and one after. So there are nine slots in total. Note that, because the books are all distinct, the blue books are distinguishable: for every one of the 9 positions, you can also order the books in 4! different ways. Then note that you can also permute the other 8 books. So your end result is $9 \cdot 4! \cdot 8! = 8709120$.

Comment: I think there are 9 places where to put the 4 books (just think of them as 1 book to place among 8 books).

Comment: oh so although 4 books might be next to each other, since they are distinct, they can be arranged differently? so blue book #1 can be in the spot #2 position? if that makes any sense?

Comment: @RoyKesserwani Sure. Just imagine you have four books that are distinct. In how many ways can you arrange those? You will find that you can arrange them in 4! = 24 ways.

Comment: @dado I don't follow your argument. If you have 8 books, and you pick out one, it can fall into 8 different slots: the first, second, third, ... or the 8th slot.

Comment: @Newb I might be very tired but you have four blue books, you are left with 8 books.  Now let an S indicate each of the remaining 8 books and - be a space (where to put all the 4 books!), then we have this configuration: -S-S-S-S-S-S-S-S- . We have 9 bars.

Comment: @Newb another way of saying this: put the non-blue 8 books in a row, now it is just a matter of choosing where to put the 4 books (thought as 1 book). We can put the 4 books before all 8 non-blue books, or between the first and the second of the non-blu books, etc etc but you can also put them aftell ALL 8 non-blue books.

Comment: @dado You're actually right. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @Newb also, i believe you need to permute the 8 remaining books as well. So the answer should be 9*8!*4!.

Comment: @dado yup, that's right. end answer: ~8 million times larger than the starting answer. nice.

Comment: @Newb it is just a matter of "estimation". You have 12! which is about 400 million possible arrangements of the books and 192 seems unrealistic, given that we have only a constraint on 4 of the books!